# confusion on servlet config

Tags: servlets

In Myeclipse I created a web project called web1,and added a servlet called servlet1,the web.xml is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

but when I typed the address:http://localhost:8080/web/test in the browser,it didn't work.I tried many times but have no answer.what's the problem?thanks a lot! 
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6214906967399177511L;

    /**
     * Constructor of the object.
     */
    public servlet1() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Destruction of the servlet. <br>
     */
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy(); // Just puts "destroy" string in log
        // Put your code here
    }

    /**
     * The doGet method of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to get.
     * 
     * @param request the request send by the client to the server
     * @param response the response send by the server to the client
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
     * @throws IOException if an error occurred
     */
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">");
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("  <HEAD><TITLE>A Servlet</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("  <BODY>");
        out.print("    This is ");
        out.print(this.getClass());
        out.println(", using the GET method");
        out.println("  </BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * The doPost method of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to post.
     * 
     * @param request the request send by the client to the server
     * @param response the response send by the server to the client
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
     * @throws IOException if an error occurred
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">");
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("  <HEAD><TITLE>A Servlet</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("  <BODY>");
        out.print("    This is ");
        out.print(this.getClass());
        out.println(", using the POST method");
        out.println("  </BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
     */
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Put your code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Is web server is running? Show us the servlet code.

Comment: It's a default servlet created by Myeclipse,I didn't add anything.

Comment: I haven't use Myeclipse so I don't know what is in default servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I will put the code in the question.

Comment: code seems goo to me. Does this class has package name? May be you need to re-start the web-server instance.

Comment: I didn't have a package.It still didn't work.

Comment: I have solved the problem.I made a mistake that I set the folder "webapps" in tomcat as the workspace for MyEclipse.So when I deployed a project,it always went wrong.And also I can't get access to the servlet.Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @XiaodanMao Please add a response and accept it, so others can benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well as usual, you forgot to say super.init(config);

```
 @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);            
    }
```

You're servlet never got initialized, because you overrode method, and forgot to call parents' init.

That's why, if you do not know the internals, do NOT override anything, except if you're sure what are you doing.